# PowerShell - How to create a script for automatic restart of windows services?

Tags: powershell, cron, restart

I have PowerShell commands to restart my windows service:

```
$Svc = Get-Service -DisplayName 'Test' -ErrorAction Stop
$Svc | Restart-Service -ErrorAction Stop
```

Now I do not know how I can automatically create powershell script which will execute those PS commands and also how to schedule that new powershell script to be executed once per day (to perform that restart).

Thank you!!!

Comment: Save it as a script and make a new task in the windows scheduler. Plenty of resources on those topics online!!

Comment: how I can save it as a script in for example C:\Temp? Can you give me some example? Thx

Comment: You type the commands in a text file and save it with a .ps1 extension.

Comment: You did not understand... I know how to do it manually... I do not know how to do it automatically..